# How to make a div with full screen when only the browser is maximized

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

I want make my div with width 100% but I want the width to be a static so when re-sizing the browser the horizontal scroll will appear (and it wouldn't when the browser is maximized)  so I don't want to make width property with `width:100%` and I don't want to grab this value from window.screen because it gives you the full screen width not the maximized browser width 
so I don't want to be like this image when the browser is not maximized 
[image]

I want like this 
[image]

and when the browser is maximized would be like (no horizontal scroll ) 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are [probably] over complicating your issue. What you have is a background (or a `div` container) of a certain width but you don't want that to *exceed* that width, so, use CSS3 width rules:

```
.div_background-image-container {
    width:100%; /* of whatever the screen size*/
    min-width:320px; /* For mobile devices or a size that you need */
    max-width:800px; /* The maximum size of this image */ 
    margin:auto; /* Centre the div*/
    display:block;
}
```

within this div you can also set the background image and set it using the CSS3 background-size attribte of `contain` where the image will cover the background space. You could also use `cover` depending on which looks best for your situation. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp .

```
.div_background-image-container {
    background: url(fingers_in_the_air.jpg);
    background-size: contain; /* OR cover, please explore */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

From this the background container box will have a minimum width of 320px and a maximum width of 800px, and within these parameters a width of 100% of the screen, so it doesn't matter the size of the browser window or the browser resolution, these constraints will hold the image and it will display proportionally according to the `background-size` CSS statement.

This also avoids Javascript and other event processing as the width is defined automatically by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.innerWidth` and `screen.width` (which gives you the maximized browser width). Make use of a conditional to decide when to show a horizontal scrollbar (for example by toggling a class on the `body` tag) and wrap this piece of code in an onresize listener.